# Inspect CSS :before elements in the web inspector

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, inspector

Is there any way to inspect elements that were added via the CSS :before selector, in the Chrome or FF web inspector and inspect their calculated styles (and manipulate them on the fly)?

Setup is

```
li:before {
    display: block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

So it's real block element without any HTML, but on inspection he only selects the related LI element. The "force element state"-option does not work either, it's only for interaction states like :hover but not :before

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I inspect and tweak :before and :after pseudoclasses in-browser?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10174719/how-can-i-inspect-and-tweak-before-and-after-pseudoclasses-in-browser)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is. Inspect the element itself (not the pseudo), the pseudo element's styles should show up below, before the inherited styles.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Okay right so that's for CSS manipulation, but I guess getting the full list of "calculated styles" is impossible?

Comment: @user1446186: I believe that much is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo elements now show in Chrome Inspector (as of Chrome 31). See the pseudo element in Chrome's built in inspector. You also can edit the css properties as you'd expect.

[image: See the pseudo element in Chrome's built in inspector]

Comment: Is there a way to _remove_ the :before or :after from the web inspector? Just curious. :)