# How to click on ::before element

Tags: python, selenium, css-selectors

I have to close the this dialog box

[image: Dialog Box]

The HTML Code of the same is

[image]

How to deal with it. There is no other option to close the dialog box.
I have tried locating element via css selector but that dint help.

**Edit**
CSS of ngdialog-close:before

```
.ngdialog.ngdialog-theme-default .ngdialog-close:before {
  background: transparent;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: #bbb;
  content: '\00D7';
  font-size: 26px;
  font-weight: 400;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 26px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 3px;
  text-align: center;
  top: 3px;
  width: 30px;
}
```

Comment: `<script>document.getElementsByClassName('ngdialog-close')[0].style.display = none;` is an easy solution is js.

Comment: why not using the class?

Comment: try to find the `Serial Number` element and then navigate to close button, using Xpath or cssSelectors. please add HTML code for `Serial Number` till `Close` button.

Comment: @frederick99 What you are suggesting is to find the div element and then do click, right?
It doesnt work. I need to do click on ::before

Comment: no. I am setting the `display` property of the element to `none`.

Comment: useful info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23719956/what-does-before-really-do

Comment: Can you provide a URL as an example?

Comment: @frederick99 your solution got me going for now, but I think that is more like a workaround because it basically hides the dialog box. in the HTML box is still present.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't click the `::before` as it is not an element, it's probably content (If it is an element than someone used bad practices behind the scenes). Chrome displays it as `::before` for debugging purposes. So I think it could be one of these:

1. Either your close button isn't a button but an icon or a gif etc...
2. You're missing the actual button which could be the `div` but it requires a hover before the click for example or it's a parent element to your `div`.
3. Your button isn't working... (does it work manually?)

If it turns out it is an element, then you can click it with Chrome dev tools opened and see what the *Styles* tab is showing, for example:

```
div::before {
  content: url(some.gif);
}
```

Perhaps it will show you the HTML code that's being added.

Comment: Your 2nd point got me going. I had to click on div but for some reason selenium `click()` was not working, even with the action chains.
So I used javascript()  click method and it solved my problem.

Comment: That's great! and a little weird that it didn't work with Selenium... However, you can see in the `content: '\00D7';` that it's just a multiplication sign and not a button. (Unicode Character U+00D7)

Answer (score 0):

U can use "Xpath". Probably isn't the best solution, but can work.
Take a look:

Firstly, i create a function that wait:

```
def waitxpath(xpath_):
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpath_))
        )
    time.sleep(1)
    return element
```

After that, to click ok button "::before" u can use a code like that:

`data_one = waitxpath('//*[@id="comunicado"]/span/i')`    `driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="comunicado"]/span/i').click()`

Well, i hope that it would be useful for u or anyone.

Page HTML:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jYj3G.png)