# what's the purpose of this "::before"?

Tags: html, css

I just understand the css ::before selector usage but cannot understand the purpose of below ::before between two div ?

```
<div id="banner" style="--vh:8.32px;"> 
::before 
<div id="banner-content" class="flex-container">
```

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Where do you see that at?

Comment: The only place I've see this is when expanding an element in the browser devtools inspect facility. Is that where you saw it?  In that context clicking on the ::before will show you the styling for that element's before pseudo element.

Comment: yes i saw it on chrome element inspection.

Answer (score -3):

`::before` is one of the [CSS Pseudo-elements](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_elements.asp). You can read more in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23719987/7313293).