# How do you inspect CSS variables in the browser?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome-devtools, web-component, css-variables

I am defining my variables [as per the spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables) like so:

```css
:root {
 --my-colour: #000;
}
```

And accessing them like this:

```css
.my-element {
  background: var( --my-colour );
}
```

Which works fine.

However I was wondering if there was a way of debugging or inspecting the `:root` CSS rule to see what variables have been defined, and what their values were?

From my understanding the `:root` selector and `html` selectors both target the same element however when I inspect the `html` element using Chrome's debugging tools I cannot see anything defined:

[image: inspecting the html element]

Is there a way finding out what variables have been defined and their values?

Comment: Maybe you can take a look at : http://stackoverflow.com/a/10175042/3365426

Comment: Thanks, I have just tried that but it just outputs the computed style of the html element not any variables.

Comment: I think you need to inspect `.my-element` to see the value of `--my-colour` variable. In the root element you can't view the value (you asked for the definition but I think the developers consoles are not prepared for this yet)

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Using Chrome Canary, you can access this by viewing the element's *Computed* styles and enabling the *Show all* filter:

> [image: Computed tab] ... [image: Example]

Comment: "`#\30 00`" Wait, what? Why does the inspector see a need to encode the first 0?

Comment: @BoltClock might be one of the reasons it's still hidden behind a flag. ;)

Comment: @BoltClock interestingly that affects any hexadecimal colour code which begins with a number (0-9). `#900` and `#777777` display as `#\39 00` and `#\37 77777` respectively, whereas `#ABC` displays as `#ABC`.

Comment: All of a sudden I recall seeing this behavior elsewhere, but I can't remember what exactly it is for the life of me. Maybe it has to do with how custom property values are stored, what CSS type they are, etc.

Comment: @BoltClock If we drop the `#` and set it to an erroneous `012345` it drops the `0` altogether (http://i.imgur.com/kA9Zani.png). :D

Comment: Ah, but you see, `012345` is being treated as an <integer> which is causing the 0 to be dropped as a non-significant digit. It's not erroneous *per se* - it just prevents that custom property from being used as a <color> value.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly cheers. This didn't work for me in my version of Chrome (v48). However when I have now downloaded Chrome Cannery and on that this can be accessed in the _Styles_ tab without the need to enable the _show all_ filter. Thanks

Comment: @Paul.B and with that comment you've made me realise that I've somehow been using Chrome Canary instead of Chrome all day! Whoops.

Comment: Starting with Canary 67, this method no longer needed, as there are handy tooltips are available, see my answer and comment below.

Comment: Unfortunately it still shows formulas for calculated values and not the real values.

Answer (score 10):

**Safari** (43) - in the developer tools, there is a little icon you can click to reveal the value.

[image]

**Firefox** (58) - in the developer tools, the CSS vars have a dotted line, when you hover, the value get's displayed as a tooltip.

[image]

**Chrome** (67) - in the developer tools, the CSS var values are also displayed as a tooltip when hovering. When the value is a color, it will display the color in a box. (hard to take a screenshot, but it looks similar to Firefox)

Comment: Weird. Wonder what's holding Chrome up here.

Comment: There you go, with Chrome 67 (current nightly Canary version) you can inspect the CSS Vars in the same way, as with the other ones. I have updated my answer accordingly. Source: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/04/devtools#vars